# Error in Clojure java.lang.Exception: transaction rolled back: d != clojure.lang.Keyword (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Tags: java, clojure

Here is my code:

```
(defn tbl_email_data
  {:new-acc  1
   :email "test_get_account_3@mode-test.co"
   :token "pa55P0rt"})

(defn create-online-test-data[data_values]
   (with-connection
      (with-transaction []
         ;Insert tbl_email
         (execute-sql (format "Insert into tbl_email (email, acc_no, pass) values          ('%s', %d, '%s')" data_values :email data_values :new-acc data_values :token))
  )))
```

When trying to run it, I get the following error:

> com.mode.test.core.testOnline=> (create-online-test-data tbl_email_data )
>   java.lang.Exception: transaction rolled back: d != clojure.lang.Keyword (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)

Comment: What library are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `format` isn't doing what you think it's doing. You're passing the map and keywords as arguments, which will cause `format` to insert a string representation of the map into the SQL string (and ignore the final three arguments).

Try this instead:

```
(format "Insert into tbl_email (email, acc_no, pass) values
         ('%s', %d, '%s')"
        (data_values :email)
        (data_values :new-acc)
        (data_values :token))
```

Or, a bit more idiomatically:

```
(apply format
       "Insert into tbl_email (email, acc_no, pass) values
        ('%s', %d, '%s')"
      (map data_values [:email :new-acc :token]))
```